# How to get the day (Mon, tue, etc... Not a number) of the computer's clock?

Tags: c#, date

I want to get the day of my computer, but in a word instead of a number. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
string day = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

Here is the [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Hm. Wonder why that didn't turn up in google. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

    Console.WriteLine("The day of the week for {0:d} is {1}.", dt, dt.DayOfWeek);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom date and time format strings
[custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```cs
string dayOfWeek = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd");
Console.WriteLine(dayOfWeek);
```

This will print out "Mon, Tue" etc